# Static website hosted on AWS S3 /Route 53 / Cloudfront not working

Tags: amazon-route53

My domain name is "bijusharman.com" . It was working until yesterday. I updated the html and css files in my S3 bucket today and started getting this problem. I created an invalidation record in cloudfront to make the changes immediately effective.

Dig on the domain alone gives : SERVFAIL Dig on the domain with one of NS present in hosted section of Route 53 gives : REFUSED.

After searching in google I realized that NS names should be consistent in both "Hosted Zones" section and"Registered Domain" section ; they were different. I updated the value in "Registered Domain" section with that of "Hosted Zones" section.

My queries :

All the while it was working fine why this problem ( if ever it si due to NS inconsistency) came now?

Will I have to wait until 2 days for the changes to be effective? Is there a quick way to get it resolved?

Thanks Biju